# Saving dates in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Sorting some data based on dates in my Android application. It is stored as follows:

```
Map<Year, Map<Month, Map<Day, Stuff>>>
```

Year, month and day are simply containing integers. This cannot be saved to Firebase database since it is a map that has a non-string key. I though about flattening this and turning it into Map. Huge compromise on the data structure since it allows data that the previous one does not(and should not) allow. However, Date isn't either a String. I tried something like this:

```
String key = String.valueOf(date.getTime());
```

And then using a data structure:

```
Map<String, Stuff>
```

Doesn't work either, it seems to use som illegal characters that the String cannot have in Firebase database. So, how would I go about making this work? Would appreciate help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would advise you to create a structure that would look like this:

```
...
date:{
   day:1,
   month:04,
   year:2016,
   timestamp:12345679979 //in milliseconds
}
```

This way you can easily index the timestamp int the security rule, do a query by Child and use the filter using start At and endAt methods where you would define the timestamps that define the ranges

Comment: This feels right but how do I structure that with my Stuff? Do I create for example MyClass{
MyDate date;
Stuff stuff;
}

This instead of mapping the date to the stuff?

Comment: Yes, That is a great way to structure.
So if you ever need to construct a Date object either from Joda or from Date you can have a getter method that returns the date in the forma "mm-dd-yyyy" and pass into the constructor. Since you already have the timestamp you can also use it for the construction

Answer (score 1):

If you use Date, you can convert it to a string with

```
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(dateObject);
```

With dateObject being the date you're working with and

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

being the format for the date. You can find formatting information about this in the [oracle Customizing Formats tutorial page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Answers the question "How do I turn a Date into a String?". This doesn't solve my problem, just behaves like turning a Long into a String(although this is worse since it requires other parties working with the database to be aware of the dateformat.) Here is the error when testing your code: "FATAL EXCEPTION Caused by: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid key: 19/09/2016. Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'"

Comment: Rather than "dd/MM/yyyy" you can try "dd-MM-yyyy" since firebase keys don't have any issues with '-'

Comment: As for the other parties having to be aware, no matter how you save it they would have to figure out what format is used anyways. Every application handles these things in a different manner.