# DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") gives different formats for different users

Tags: c#, date, datetime, string-formatting, date-conversion

I assumed that `ToString("yyyy/MM/dd  HH:mm:ss")` will force the string to be formatted with '/', but I can see that every device gets different formats. How can I force it to be saved with '/'?

Good example-

- `2021/10/06  18:05:53`

Strange examples I see in my DB from different users-

- `2021-10-06 23:48:37`
- `2021.10.12  12:41:42`
- `2021. 10. 06  19:17:23`  ('.'+ space after)
- `2021.10.13  19.18.16`

One solution is to replace every `-`, `.` and `.` to `/`, but this only solves the strange examples I found. What if there are others?

Comment: You could always store the datetime as ticks (bigint for sql, long for C#). Then convert back to DateTime in the calling application or when running a query via built in sql date formatting.

Comment: Just to be clear - is the date stored in the DB as a string or a datetime? Are you calling `ToString` _after_ you get the data from the DB or are you storing the data after calling `ToString` and looking directly in the DB ?

Comment: Saved as a string in the DB (after ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"))

Comment: *Saved as a string in the DB* - epic fail, change ASAP

Comment: I can't, that's what Firebase real-time DB offers. Only string, long, int

Comment: If it's even possible to see different examples from different users in your DB, you've already made a **HUGE** mistake. The solution for the "what if there are others?" problem is pretty much any database worth using has a `DATETIME` type. Saving these values into a column with that type will fix these things for you, plus give you accurate date math (for example: querying across ranges) and indexes, which can _dramatically_ speed up your queries.

Comment: As I mentioned before- I use Firebase RealTime Database, it's not possible to store DATETIME in Firebase as much as I want. I understand that it's not the best but that's the tools they give me and I need to work with that

Comment: I came back to this today, and I think you may be confusing the transfer with the storage. I believe Firebase effectively uses json as it's data transfer mechanism, which does not have native date support, but the documentation [clearly shows](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types) it does have a [date/time storage type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp).

Comment: Hey, the link you shared is for Firebase Firestore, but I use Firebase Realtime DB, which can't store dates. I can only store string, int,  long, double, bool. My solution is to either convert the Date to string or to a structure which will contain string int and long [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/` in a format string means "the culture-specific date separator". If you want the literal forward-slash, quote it (and the colons, to avoid the use of a custom time separator):

```cs
ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd HH':'mm':'ss")
```

Alternatively - and probably better - use the invariant culture. Not only will that use `/` as the date separator, but you won't need to worry about a culture having a different default calendar. (It'll always use the Gregorian calendar, which is presumably what you want.)

Even better, use an ISO-8601 format - you're already using a "slightly unusual for humans" format of year-first, so you might as well go the whole hog and go with the *standard* format for dates and times.

Sample code:

```cs
String text = dateTimeValue.ToString(
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This is also the [*sortable standard date/time format*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Sortable) so you can simplify the code significantly:

```cs
String text = dateTimeValue.ToString("s");
```

(That format always uses the invariant culture.)

That's if you really need to format the string at all, though. If you're saving it in a database, I'd advise you to:

- Use an appropriate type in the database, e.g. DATETIME
- Store it using a parameter (specifying the value just as a `DateTime`), not formatted text

If you do both of these, you'll avoid oddities like this.

Comment: Thanks. I can't save DateTime, only as a string. That's why I need to save it in one format. I use DateTime.Parse when importing back from DB. And realized that I can't Parse wrong formats- those without the slash. What do you mean by "use the invariant culture"? How?

Comment: @SHAI: You pass it as a second argument. I'll put an example in my code. But I would really try to find a way of avoiding using a string if possible.

Comment: I can't, because my DB can only store int and strings

Comment: @SHAI: That sounds like a pretty poor database solution :( Oh well - I've added sample code, and made another suggestion which is *not* to use a slash, but instead use the ISO standard for date/time strings.

Comment: I'm trying to see how to test it. Since I can't use string.ToString(
    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);  it has to be a DateTime.tostring() but only certain mobiles create that error DateTime.   I found out that 2021.10.13 19.18.16  is the date that caused all my issues because it can't be parsed because the periods are everywhere

Comment: Re the sample code, how about using the sortable pattern, `dateTimeValue.ToString("s")` ?

Comment: @CaiusJard: Yup, that works too - I'll add that in there. Thanks.

Comment: @SHAI: You should be able to reproduce the problem with your previous code by changing culture. (Try French or Italian, for example.) Then once you've reproduced it, you can test the fix.

Comment: Let me summarize the solution. Instead of my code which is `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd  HH:mm:ss")`  , I need to use `DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s")`  which will always save the date in the same way from every device? No more custom line separators?

Comment: @JonSkeet *a pretty poor database solution* - soo.. when you're next in the office, can you drop by their department and sort it out? 

Comment: @SHAI: Yes - or store the value as a number instead. (e.g. using a number of ticks). That would be more efficient, but slightly harder to inspect and may be harder to use in some platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that I can think of is creating a new function that creates a date
`DateTime date= DateTime.UtcNow;` 
And extracting manually and splitting the date to a few strings (year,month,day,hour,month,seconds)

`string year = date.Year.ToString(); string month = date.Month.ToString();...`
and building a string out of it in the right format,
`string newDate= year + "/" + month + "/" + day + "  "+ hour+":"+ minute+ ":"+seconds;`
that way I can be sure it's always one format that I'll decide on

Comment: Or use `DateTime.ToString("s")`, or `"o"`, or unix time, or a different db 

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the date as a number, eg unix time - `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()` or `(DateTime.UtcNow - DateTime.UnixEpoch).TotalSeconds` - it's a lot simpler and cheaper to store a number than a string

Also wanted to point out that the only date I've
seen you store so far is UtcNow (as written in your answer) - fire base does appear to have a solution for that in that you can send `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` and it will cause fb to store the unix time as the server sees it.

My take away from this (never used fb) is that that's how *they* store dates so perhaps it makes sense to follow :)

Comment: Thanks. I use Firebase Realtime database and not Firestore. I can store int, long and string. In any case, I'll have to do a conversion- [Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data). And here is another solution from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39572668/saving-dates-in-firebase-database/39574701)